# Laravel7 Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::find()

Tags: laravel-7

in my Laravel 7 app when i go to a page i am getting this

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::find()
```

In my app/Http/Controllers/clientController.php I have

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Client;

class ClientController extends Controller {

  public function viewclient(Request $id)
  {
    $client = DB::find($id);
    return view('viewclient', compact('client', 'id'));
    
  }

}
```

In my app/Client.php I have

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Client extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'clients';
}
```

Not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should mention the table name when use query builder :

```
$client = DB::find($id); // no table here
```

Change to

```
$client = DB::table('clients')->find($id); // here 'clients' is your table name
```

See [Official Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#retrieving-results)